# ETH transaction sent at a very low gas price, failed, but still says pending

Tags: gas

I am using Atomic Wallet, and I sent some ETH to an online exchange.

The (1) first time it Failed from Etherscan status at 9 Gwei and and Gas Limit of 21,000. It said 100% limit was used.

The (2) second time, I used 6 Gwei and Gas Limit of 29,243, and it failed because 100% gas limit was used. This transaction took 2 hours and 8 minutes.

Due to the fear that I set a value too low, I sent a very small (3) third transaction to "replace" this one, thereby cancelling it, but I could not set the nonce value, and thus, it was different than the previous transaction. So it was a waste at the end. And it Failed as well as the Gas limit 100 % was reached.

My concern now is that, on my Atomic Wallet it is saying that these last two transactions are still pending, but on Etherscan, the status is "Fail". "Out of gas". So what do I do now to get the ETH onto the exchange? Should I wait for the Atomic Wallet to remove the Pending status, or send it again? And, if so at what Gas Price and Gas Limit? I would like it up there within 30 mins or so.

Thank you very much, 
R.K

Comment: Can you please share your transaction hash?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x578839bcd1f4c9e8c9bf9569d3ff6a8a1fe2e2b6d9aa88a81333ef11761a644d

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb5b8f7cf491719b490f22602466badd53d8d411a29a0afca54afb435ab3027f8

Comment: **the situation has fixed itself. The transaction took a long time, and even though it said pending, my wallet still had the ETH in there. I was able to send it again at a higher gas price, and it worked**